# 1st Edition missprints on base set pikachu

Tags: pokemon

Hello there I've trying to get my hands on a rare miss printed base set pikachu. Where the 1st edition symbol is faded, aka the (ghost print). I just wondered is the pikachu on the right is a (ghost print). Thanks for your help.[image]

Comment: From what I see in the pictures the card just looks damaged.

Comment: So its not a miss print of the 1st edition symbol? the one on the right is a normal one and the photo is bad quality.

Comment: With the quality of the picture provided, it is difficult to properly evaluate the condition of the card. At best, the card on the right looks like it was sanded or roughed up.

Comment: Ok thanks for your opinions they are much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It does not appear that this is a "Ghost Stamp Pikachu". I checked online and found several for sale that are slabbed and rated, but the "First Edition" marker looks quite different than yours, with parts of it missing:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note that all of these genuine "Ghost Stamp Pikachu" cards are also Yellow Cheek Pikachu cards, so you are on the right track with it being a Ghost Print.

Answer (score 4):

Referencing Thunderforge's images, I'd like to add to what he said. He was right that you do not have a "Ghost" misprint 1st Edition Shadowless Pikachu. However the Pikachu you have is not damaged. It is a valid misprint. It is know as a 1st Edition "Grey Stamp" Shawdowless Pikachu. It is a niche in the pokemon card collector world, but definitely worth more than the regular 1st Edition Shadowless Pikachu. I have one and I love it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Perhaps this would be more appropriate as a comment rather than a new answer?

Comment: @Thunderforge PikachuCollector would need to have 50 reputation to comment on your answer.